# How to execute Javascript alert when page loads the first time only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to execute a javascript alert, but only alert if it is the first time that browser / computer has viewed that page - or something similar to that. 
How would this be done? I have written the Javascript to what I think it be similar to.

```
function alert() {
    alert(" Please view this is Firefox");
}
if (first time viewing this page) {
    alert();
}
```

I really appreciate your help

Comment: are you interested in using local storage?

Comment: Use a cookie: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: are you using asp.net application ?

Comment: You might want to be careful about calling your declared function `alert` and then trying to call `alert()` inside it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [**JQuery Cookie Plugin**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for this.

```
function showPopUp() {
    var cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
    if(!cookie){
        alert(" Please view this in Firefox");
        $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
    }
}
showPopUp();
```

Comment: don't you think that `alert` is a bad name for custom function?

Comment: @Dharmang you are right it is. I have changed the function name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `localStorage` or `cookies`:

Here is an example with `localStorage`:

```
var visited = localStorage.getItem('visited');
if (!visited) {
  alert("Please view this is Firefox");
  localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `Cookie` it will be sent to the server at each time your make request. You can use `Local Storage` instead, like:

```
function load() {
  var isFired = localStorage.getItem('checkFired');

  if (isFired != '1'){
      alert(" Please view this is Firefox");
      localStorage.setItem('checkFired', '1');
  }
}
load();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set cookie**

```
document.cookie="first=first";
```

**Read a Cookie with JavaScript**

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

**Example:**

```
function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}

function checkCookie()
{
  var first=getCookie("first");
  if(first == "first")
  {
    alert(" Please view this is Firefox");
  }else{
    document.cookie="first=first";
  }
}
```

[Cookie in JS](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

See this link you will get some idea [example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username) is based on cookies...Once you typed you value and if you refresh it, it will show the value..